# How to add dependencies (and repositories) dynamically in a custom Gradle plugin task using Kotlin dsl

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

The title basically says it all.

I am trying to create a plugin that can be configured and depending on the configuration, the task provided by the plugin adds compileOnly or implementation deppendencies to the project.

The resources on writing custom Gradle plugins are abhorrent (especially in Kotlin instead of Groovy) and I can't figure out how to do this myself.

This is where I'm at with my custom plugin code:

```
class SpigotVersioner: Plugin<Project> {

  override fun apply(project: Project) {

    println("Latest spigot version: ${WebScraper.getLatestVersion()}")

    val extension = project.extensions.create("spigot", SpigotExtension::class.java)

    extension.apiVersion.set("latest")
    extension.bukkitVersion.set("latest")

    project.task("compileSpigotAPI") {
      it.group = "spigot"
      it.description = "Adds the spigot api implementation to the project."

      it.doLast {
        val apiVersion = extension.apiVersion.get()
        val dependency = deriveDependencyStr(apiVersion)

        //DOESN'T WORK!
        project.dependencies {
          compileOnly(dependency)
        }

        //WHAT ARE THESE PARAMETERS SUPPOSED TO BE?
        project.dependencies.add(configurationName: String, dependencyNotation: Any)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is supposed to mimic something like

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly 'my.derived.dependency.str:apiVersion:xy'
}
```

only the dependency being added is supposed to be configurable via an extension.

If possible, I'd like to extend this to also add the appropriate repository as well but the dependency issue is more important.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of an old question now, but I too struggled with this so hopefully this answer is of use to someone.

> //WHAT ARE THESE PARAMETERS SUPPOSED TO BE?
> project.dependencies.add(configurationName: String, dependencyNotation: Any)

The `configurationName` is the configuration that you wish to add the dependency to e.g. `implementation`, `testImplementation` or `api` etc.

The `dependencyNotation` can be any of the following:

- String Notation: Simply a String written using Gradle dependency notation e.g. `com.mycompany:my-awesome-dependency:1.2.3`. There are ways to also specify things like strictness when using these 'simple' declarations, this is somewhat documented [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/single_versions.html#simple_version_declaration_semantics).
- Map Notation: This is where you pass a Map<String, String> containing key-value pairs representing the dependency. The documentation on this is either non existent or elusive, but for example: `"group": "com.mycompany", "name": "my-awesome-dependency", "version": "1.2.3"`.
- Dependency Interface: This is where you pass in an object that implements one of the `Dependency` interfaces that the Gradle API provides. The most basic being `org.gradle.api.artifacts.Dependency`. The main issue with this method is again that the documentation is either elusive or non-existent. I cannot see a way to have Gradle create one of these objects (or see any pre implemented classes in the public API). You could always just implement the interface but there are some methods on there like `contentEquals` and `copy()` which seem overkill to implement.

My recommendation if it suits your use case would be to use the first option above.